# Ubuntu with multiple desktop sessions

Tags: discussion

Should we here on Ask Ubuntu necessary attempt to answer all questions regardless of desktop interface that person is using? Being that you can install so many different ones [Cinnamon, Gnome, Unity (default), Gnome classic, ect].

My point is that: with all the desktop sessions should we only focus on only the default sessions that come distributed with Ubuntu or should we attempt to answer all questions regardless of desktop session even if it be something like cinnamon and not necessarily Ubuntu?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, all the desktops, window managers, dock programs, etc. The FAQ reads:

> - Using and administering Ubuntu, including official Ubuntu derivatives.
> - Running third-party applications on Ubuntu.

There's no reason to exclude other desktops.

Answer (score 1):

It would be rather silly for us to support *universe*, *multiverse*, third-party repo, and PPA packages in general, plus binary-only proprietary apps (both native and in Wine) ...*except* when it's a desktop environment.

We help people run MATLAB on Ubuntu. There's no reason not to help people run MATE.

Answer (score -3):

No, only the ones for supported distributions.

Comment: It seems that you posted two conflicting answers

Comment: no, they are "yes and no" options for people to vote, If you have arguments for either edit them in, and vote for the one you want.